# SQLite Composite key error

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Why am I getting an error with the following statement?

`create table if not exists patient_to_prescs(`

`patient_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES patients_table(id)`

`presc_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES prescs_table(id)`

`PRIMARY KEY(patient_id, presc_id))`

This is in android and the error is 
`near "prescs_id": syntax error(code 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this, you are missing ",":

```
create table if not exists patient_to_prescs(

patient_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES patients_table(id),

presc_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES prescs_table(id),

PRIMARY KEY(patient_id, presc_id));
```